# How to compute a free algebra for a given algebra over a set?

Tags: universal-algebra, universal-property

This is a question from a "demo exam" a few years ago at out university course.

**The question:** How would you compute the free algebra for $\mathcal{A}$ over $X = \{x, y  \}$, where $\mathcal{A} = \{ \{ 0, 1, 2 \}, \ast \}$?

The operation $\ast$ is defined:

\begin{array}{ |c|c|c|c| }
\hline
∗& 0& 1& 2 \\
\hline 
0 &0 &1& 1\\
\hline 
1 &1& 0&0\\
\hline 
2 & 0&0& 1\\
\hline 
\end{array}

**My thoughts:**
If I simply start with definitions, an algebra $\mathcal{F}$ is free for $\mathcal{A}$ over $X$ iff $X \in \mathcal{F}$ and for every $A$ from $\mathcal{A}$ and every $h: X \rightarrow A$, there exists a $\overline{h}:  \mathcal{F} \rightarrow A$ such that $h$ is the restriction of $\overline{h}$ on $X$.

But then, I am stuck. Maybe we should take an arbitrary $X$ from $\mathcal{A}$, for example $\{0, 1 \}$, and an arbitrary map $h: \{x, y \} \rightarrow \{0, 1 \}$ that maps $x$ to $0$ and $y$ to $1$. And then find the $\overline{h}$ that "extends" the $h$ somehow?

But honestly, I have no idea, how to construct a free algebra just from this information. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is asking for the free algebra over $X=\{x,y\}$ in the variety $\sf V = {\sf H}{\sf S}{\sf P}(\mathcal A)$. This free algebra has 130 elements, so I doubt you are expected to actually construct it. Rather, it seems likely that they only want you to explain the procedure for constructing it.

One standard construction for ${\mathcal F}_{\sf V}(\{x,y\})$ is as a subalgebra of the algebra ${\mathcal A}^{{\mathcal A}^2}$. The $\underline{\textrm{set}}$ $A^{A^2}$ consists of all functions $f\colon A^2\to A$. We may regard $x$ and $y$ as elements of this set of functions by identifying $x$ with binary first-coordinate projection ($x(u,v) = u$) and $y$ with binary second-coordinate projection ($y(u,v)=v$). The $\underline{\textrm{algebra}}$ ${\mathcal A}^{{\mathcal A}^2}$ is this set of functions under pointwise operations from $\mathcal A$. One construction of ${\mathcal F}_{\sf V}(\{x,y\})$ is as the subalgebra of ${\mathcal A}^{{\mathcal A}^2}$ generated by the subset $\{x,y\}$.

More concretely, order the elements of $A^2$ lexicographically as
$$\langle (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)\rangle.$$
These 9 elements can be taken as indices of coordinates of tuples for elements of $A^{A^2}$. With this representation, the function table for first projection $x$ may be represented as $[x]:=\langle 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2\rangle\in A^9$, and the function table for the second projection $y$ may be represented as $[y]:=\langle 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2\rangle\in A^9$. To get ${\mathcal F}_{\sf V}(\{x,y\})$, generate a subalgebra of ${\mathcal A}^{9}$ with $[x], [y]$.
This means, start with $[x]=\langle 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2\rangle, [y]=\langle 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2\rangle\in A^9$ and close under coordinatewise multiplication.

**EDIT 1/8/22.**

In response to a comment, I will explain why the $2$-generated free algebra in the variety generated by ${\mathcal A}$
has size $130$. Moreover I will explain how to
$*$-multiply any two elements of this $130$-element set.

In order to avoid writing too many bracketed variables, I will use the letter $a$ to denote $[x]$ from above, and the letter $b$ to denote $[y]$ from above.

Observe that

- any product of elements of $A$ lies in the subset $B = \{0,1\}$, and
- the product operation of $A$ restricted to $B=\{0,1\}$
  is addition modulo $2$.

In particular, $B=\{0,1\}$
is the underlying set of a subalgebra of $\mathcal A$
and the algebra structure on $B$ is
equivalent to that of a $2$-element group,
or equivalent to that of a $1$-dimensional vector space
over $\mathbb F_2$.

These facts mean that the subalgebra $\mathcal F$
of ${\mathcal A}^9$
that is generated by
$a = \langle 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2\rangle$
and $b=\langle 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2\rangle$ has
the property that the product of any two
elements lies in $B^9 = \{0,1\}^9$, which is a
$9$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_2$
under the $*$-operation. Hence the underlying set
of $\mathcal F$ must have the form $\{a,b\}\cup V$
for some $\mathbb F_2$-subspace $V\leq B^9$.
I claim that this $V$ is a $7$-dimensional subspace,
and I will tell you which one it is.

Write a typical element of $A^9$ as
$z = \langle z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5,z_6,z_7,z_8,z_9\rangle$.
Observe that if $z$ is one of the generators of $\mathcal F$,
$a = \langle 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2\rangle$
or $b=\langle 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2\rangle$, the
following hold:

- $z_1, z_2, z_4, z_5\in B$, and the following
  linear relations hold among these coordinates:
- $z_1 = 0$, and
- $z_2+z_4+z_5 = 0$.

The relations are preserved under the $*$-operation
acting coordinatewise. (Reason:
the generators have coordinates $z_1, z_2, z_4, z_5\in B$,
so the projection of $\mathcal F$ onto these coordinates is a
vector subspace of $B^4$ with respect to $*$ and this vector space
is generated by vectors $\langle a_1,a_2,a_4,a_5\rangle = \langle 0, 0, 1, 1\rangle$ and $\langle b_1,b_2,b_4,b_5\rangle = \langle 0, 1, 0, 1\rangle$, which satisfy these linear relations.)
This implies that the underlying set
of $\mathcal F$ is $\{a, b\}\cup V$ where in every $z\in V$
we have $z_1=0$ and $z_2+z_4+z_5=0$. The two linear relations
guarantee that $V$ has codimension at least $2$
in the $9$-dimensional space $B^9$, so $V$ is at most
$7$-dimensional. But $V$ is exactly $7$-dimensional,
since I can exhibit $7$ independent vectors in $V$, namely:

- $a((ba)b) = \langle 0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0\rangle$
- $a(b(ab)) = \langle 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0\rangle$
- $b((ab)a) = \langle 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0\rangle$
- $b(a(ab)) = \langle 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0\rangle$
- $(aa)(b(b(aa))) = \langle 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1\rangle$
- $a(a(ba)) = \langle 0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0\rangle$
- $a((ab)(bb)) = \langle 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0\rangle$

(In the products on the left of the equal signs I am abbreviating
$*$-products $p*q$ by $pq$.)
Altogether, this shows that the underlying set of $\mathcal F$
is $\{a, b\}\cup V$ where $V\leq B^9$ is the $7$-dimensional subspace
of all $z = \langle z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5,z_6,z_7,z_8,z_9\rangle$
satisfying $z_1=0$ and $z_2+z_4+z_5=0$.
This allows us to determine the size of $\mathcal F$:
it is $2+|V|=2+2^7 = 130$.

We can do more than determine the size of this algebra, we can even determine
how the $*$-operation interprets on the set $\{a,b\}\cup V$.
One may verify that:

- $aa = \langle 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1\rangle\in V$
- $ab = \langle 0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1\rangle\in V$
- $ba = \langle 0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1\rangle\in V$
- $bb = \langle 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1\rangle\in V$

This explains how to $*$-multiply one element of $\{a,b\}$
times another. One may also verify that if $z\in B^9$ then

- $az = \langle z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4',z_5',z_6',0,0,0\rangle\in V$
- $za = \langle z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4',z_5',z_6',z_7'z_8'z_9'\rangle\in V$
- $bz = \langle z_1,z_2',0,z_4,z_5',0,z_7,z_8',0\rangle\in V$
- $zb = \langle z_1,z_2',z_3'z_4,z_5',z_6',z_7,z_8',z_9'\rangle\in V$

Here I am writing primes on variables to mean: swap
$0$ and $1$ (that is, $0'=1, 1'=0$).
These four rules explain how to $*$-multiply an element of $\{a,b\}$
times an element $z\in V$. Finally, we already know how to $*$-multiply
two elements $z, w\in V$ since $*$ is addition modulo $2$ coordinatewise on $V$.

Altogether this identifies the $130$ tuples comprised by the subalgebra of ${\mathcal A}^9$ generated by $\{a,b\}$, and how the $*$-algebra acts on these $130$ tuples. Usually it is hard to give this much detail without the use of a computer, but we were lucky here that ${\mathcal A}$ is close
to being a $1$-dimensional $\mathbb F_2$-vector space.

Comment: This is very nice! Just when I thought I had to try to get which identities are satisfied by the algebra in order to to make the quotient $T(x,y)/\Theta$, where $\Theta$ is the intersection of congruences given by those identities. All apparently relevant(?) information I was able to get was that, with $K=\{\mathcal A\}$, we have $IS(K)$ consists of a trivial algebra and the two-element group, but that didn't take me very far...

Comment: @Keith Kearnes This is excellent! I just wanted to ask:  Why is #elements = 130 in the free algebra?

Answer (score 2):

The free $\mathcal A$-algebra over $X$ is an $\mathcal A$-algebra $A$ along with an injective map $i:X\to A$ satisfying the following universal property:

> For any $\mathcal A$-algebra $B$ and any map between sets $f:X\to B$ there is a unique map between $\mathcal A$-algebras $g:A\to B$ such that $f=g\circ i$.

This is effectively given by the algebra
$$A=\bigoplus_{w\in X^*}\mathcal A w\,,$$
where the $A$-bilinear multiplication is concatenation of words ($X^*$ denotes the set of words on the alphabet $X$).

**Edit:** Upon a closer read of your post, it's not entirely clear to me what structure $\mathcal A$ has. I believe an algebra has to be defined over (at least) a ring so the operations make sense, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Yes, you made a confusion. There is the notion of algebra over a ring, but in the context of Universal Algebra, an algebra is just a set $A$ together with a set $F$ of operations on $A$, i.e., $f:A^n\to A$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ and each $f\in F$. Then, we actually use the notation $(A,f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ for $F=\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$.

Comment: For example, a group, in which we consider the binary product, the unary inverse and the nullary identity element as operations is represented as an algebra $(G,\cdot,^{-1},1)$; a semigroup is an algebra $(S,\cdot)$, etc.

Comment: I see. I indeed did not know this notion. Thank you for the clarification.